# Why is it "s" the prefix tag used for HTTPService?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile

In my Mobile Flex project I declare a HTTPService :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="" >
    <fx:Style>
        .myClass { color: Red }
    </fx:Style>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="http://localhost/tabletteNR/NR.php" useProxy="false" method="POST"> // it causes an error "Impossible to resolve <fx:HTTPService> as a component implementation"
            <fx:request xmlns="">
                <username>a</username>
                <emailaddress>b</emailaddress>
            </fx:request>
        </fx:HTTPService>
    </fx:Declarations>
    ...
```

When I change the "fx" prefix to "s" then the error disappeared ! So why is "s" the right prefix ? However I looked the package explorer and I did not find the HHTPService inside the spark.swc folder, but I saw it inside the rpc.swc -> mx.rpc.http package. So why is it "s" the right prefix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTPService class is in the "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" library namespace; and at the top of the view tag you gave that namespace a value of s:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="" >
```

This is the default, BTW, but you can change it to anything you want.  In theory something like this should work:

```
<s:View xmlns:notfx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:fx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="" >

<notfx:Style>
    .myClass { color: Red }
</notfx:Style>
<notfx:Declarations>
    <fx:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="http://localhost/tabletteNR/NR.php" useProxy="false" method="POST"> // it causes an error "Impossible to resolve <fx:HTTPService> as a component implementation"
        <fx:request xmlns="">
            <username>a</username>
            <emailaddress>b</emailaddress>
        </fx:request>
    </fx:HTTPService>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Although it is unusual and seems like a lot of work.

The namespace URLs and the classes inside the namespace are defined in a manifest.xml file which can be created as part of the SWC.  Most Flex Developer's I know do not bother to change them.

Comment: @pheromix It is created as part of a SWC.  You can change any SWC's extension to a zip file and unzip it to find the manifest.  Some more info: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_31.html If you get the Apache Flex source; they should be in there somewhere; one for each sWC.

Answer (score 0):

To use Spark controls, default prefix is s and to use MX controls, default prefix is mx.

```
xmlns:s = "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx = "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
```

Comment: So what should be the prefix to use for HTTPService ? Is there a namespace setting missing in my code ?

Comment: What's missing from Amit's answer is that 'mx' is the original prefix of HTTPService. In mobile projects the mx namespace is not used (for performance reasons), however some classes (like HTTPService) from the mx days must still be accessible, so they were wrapped in the 's' (i.e. Spark) namespace.

Comment: I gotta -1 one this because I don't believe it does anything to address the original question of "Why is 's' the right prefix".

Comment: Reboog I already mentioned that s is the default and is configurable. You can change it xmlns:spark = "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"

Comment: @AmitKumaruser3037405 You didn't mention it is configurable. You also didn't address the "Why"

Comment: in the code snippet it is clear that s and mx are defined here and can be changed. So I didn't spent time to explain in detail as it was clearly understood.